# Producing Natural Sound with Electric Double Bass

Tags: amplifiers, orchestral-strings, double-bass

I'm looking into buying a double bass and have been considering an electric.
I know this is similar to a previous question, [how do i make an electric upright bass sound more standard](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/110449/how-do-i-make-an-electric-upright-bass-sound-more-standard), but I'm asking with a slightly different specific, so maybe this isn't a dupe.

My primary application would be to play along with a small amateur strings group, so I want a decently realistic tone. Owning an electric violin I know these are a tad off, but not far enough to really cause an issue for my taste. I just want to prevent a more digital sound coming from an amp, so I'm wondering if using am acoustic amp, such as those that Orange makes would help. Since they basically work by maintaining high fidelity to prevent "electric" coloring I wouldn't expect the amp to make it sound more acoustic, but maybe closer than a usual guitar amp, for example. Additionally, would it be better to use a bass amp since it would be made for the lower registers, making an acoustic amp kinda moot?

Comment: Separate point, there didn't seem to be much of a consensus on whether using an acoustic pedal/sim would provide "natural" warmth to help replicate that sound.

Comment: Are you going to primarily be playing arco or pizzicato?

Comment: This does seem like a duplicate to me; both questions boil down to "How do I make my electric instrument sound more like an acoustic." I'll add an answer there but keep your situation in mind.

Comment: It would also help to know what music you (and that group) usually play: "strings group" may involve classical music (which is also an extremely wide range of music styles), but we cannot be certain about it. Also, how large is that group? Are you going to be the only double bass player there?

Comment: I would primarily play pizzicato, though bowed as well. Likely, I'd be the only double bass in a group of about 6-7 various strings. No specific genre of music is played, we could play classical, modern scores, things written by members.

Comment: @AndyBonner, your answer is helpful.